# ¿Cómo puedo ignorar un caracter en html5?

Tags: html5

Estoy aprendiendo HTML y quiero hacer una lista con las etiquetas que se comportan como elementos de bloque y demás pero a la hora de poner, por ejemplo, la etiqueta `<p></p>` la toma la instrucción y no la deja visualizar. Por eso pregunto, ¿existe alguna forma de ignorar un caracter (en este caso el "<" que es el que abre la instrucción) para poder poner libremente las etiquetas?

En Java existe el "`\`" y con eso se omite el siguiente caracter, ¿hay algo así aquí?

En código se ve algo así

```
 <ul>
     <li>
          La etiqueta...
     </li>
 </ul>
```

[image: Tampoco puedo mostrar aquí cómo quiero que se vea, pero espero se entienda]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En *HTML* no puedes ignorar el caracter directamente, para mostrar esos caracteres debes utilizar **entidades de caracter** ya que en *HTML* se usa el `<` tanto como `>` para las etiquetas y también muchos otros caracteres que no puedes utilizar directamente, entonces es necesario que te aprendas algunas entidades como ser `&lt;` para `<` y `&gt;` para `>`.

En tu caso seria de la siguiente forma:

```html
<ul>
     <li>
          La etiqueta &lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Si quieres ver la lista de entidades puedes hacerlo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/CHARSETS/ref_html_8859.asp).

Te dejo una pequeña captura de la página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate en la columna **Entity name**. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Los equivalentes de escape serían: `&lt` (less than) para `<` y `&gt` (greater than) para `>`

```html
 <ul>
     <li>
          La etiqueta  &ltp&gt 
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias. Pero, ¿no existe algo como el slash invertido entonces en HTML? ¿De qué forma puedo buscar para más información acerca de estas "expresiones"? Porque quizá más adelante me encuentre con que quiero poner otro elemento del estilo y no me deje o algo así...

Answer (score 1):

Si las hay yo también hice eso en mis apuntes porque quería agregar la etiqueta, pero me lo tomaba como si en verdad quisiera usar la etiqueta.
Tienes que hacer uso de los siguientes caracteres [Códigos HTML](https://ascii.cl/es/codigos-html.htm).

Por ejemplo el código HTML para `<` es `&#60;` y ya en tu web se mostrará el carácter de menor que.

Por lo tanto para mostrar la etiqueta `p` necesitas buscar el código de los caracteres que conforman la etiqueta, cambiarlos en el mensaje y ya no tomara esos caracteres como si fuera la etiqueta verdadera.

```html
&#60;p&#62; contenido del párrafo &#60;&#47;p&#62;
```

Espero que te haya servido :)

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres mostrar cosas sin que lo etiquete como parte del html también lo puedes agregar como texto de la siguiente manera.

```js
 
   document.querySelector("div").innerText ="<p>i am a paragraph</p>";
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

no es necesario que estés poniendo códigos que abran y cierren `<>` tan solo reemplaza el primer `<` y ya con eso lo demás te lo toma como texto entonces quedaría algo así:

```html
&lt;p> &lt;/p>
```

pd: es la única observación que note y se me hizo curioso que con tan solo usando una parte del código ya te permitía mostrar el código `html`.

Suerte!